# JavaScript Change bgcolor and text

Tags: javascript, text, background

I'm trying to change the background color of the whole document and this should work. Changing the text should be the same right? I've been messing with the code and I haven't found an easy way to code the changes.

```
<style>
function bgPick()
{
    if(document.displayOptions.value == 1){
        body.background-color:blue;
    }
    else if(document.displayOptions.value == 2){
        body.background-color:cyan;
    }
    else{
        body.background-color:white;
    }
}
</style>


<form name="displayOptions">
<select name="colorPick" onchange="bgPick()">
<option value=0>Background Color</option>
<option value=1>Blue</option>
<option value=2>Cyan</option>
<option value=3>White</option>
</select>
<select name="textPick">
<option value=0>Font Color</option>
<option value=1>Black</option>
<option value=2>Red</option>
<option value=3>Silver</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: You are all sorts of confused about how CSS and Javascript work, aren't you?

Answer (score 1):

you're not supposed to insert scripts between `<style>` tags

here, two links to help you get started:

- [CSS tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/css/)
- [Javascript tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp)

Answer (score 0):

RASG is right, you should read a JavaScript tutorial first before trying to implement something like that...

```
<script>
function bgPick() {
    var select = document.querySelector("select[name='colorPick']"),
        color;
    switch (select.value) {
        case "1":  color = "blue";  break;
        case "2":  color = "cyan";  break;
        default:   color = "white"; break;
    }
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
</script>
```